# Rename file in bash by removing part of the original name

Tags: regex, bash, file

Just starting in bash and I'm stuck with a trivial (i think) problem.

I have a directory with several zip files in it like:

```
102-123.zip
54-458.zip
1566-akka.zip
```

I want to make a bash script to remove the XXX- in the zip name to have:

```
123.zip
458.zip
akka.zip
```

I'm starting with a

```
for fName in /mydirectory/*
do
    mv fname newfname
done
```

I tried starting with regexes but i'm going on things very complicated for this.

Do you have any idea on what i could do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `rename` you can do:

```
rename 's/^[^-]+-//' *.zip
```

If `rename` utility isn't available then use:

```
for f in *.zip; do
   mv "$f" "${f#*-}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to recursively rename in sub directories, use `find` :

```
find . -type f -name '*.zip' -print0 | xargs -L 1 -0 bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1#*-}"' \;
```